# Как сделать рамку вокруг ImageView?

Tags: java, android

Вот у меня есть `ImageView` с установленной в нем картинкой... Мне нужно сделать черную окантовку вокруг этой картинки... Вот один скриншот как у меня сейчас и один как мне нужно... Кто делал такое подскажите плиз уже час сижу не могу найти как это прицепить...

**вот так сейчас**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**вот так нужно**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**вот код**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="54">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25sp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/manface" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25sp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/womanface" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Создайте xml файл.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Этот бордер вставьте как `android:background="@drawable/black_border"` в ваш `imageView`